# What does "Anal. Calcd." stand for written out?

Tags: notation

I'm wondering what the abbreviation "Anal. Calcd. stands for *exactly*. It is put in front of calculated (expected) values for elemental analyses. "Analytically calculated" makes no sense for me, but maybe it's more of a language problem for me in this particular case. According to a quick Google research, some are listing it in their lists of abbreviations as "Analytical Calculated". Using the adjective instead of an adverb doesn't make it any more correct to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are two distinct terms, that just happen to frequently be found next to each other. Their definitions can be found in the [Journal of Organic Chemistry Guidelines for Authors](http://pubs.acs.org/paragonplus/submission/joceah/joceah_authguide.pdf) (see page 29).

**Anal. - abbreviation for combustion elemental analysis.**

**Calcd - abbreviation for calculated.**

It is not actually a single phrase, as you've suggested here. Combustion elemental analysis is what people often mean when referring to 'getting an analytical done'. Writing Anal. signifies the type of experimental data that is about to be listed, just as you might specify 1H NMR, IR or MS. A common alternative to combustion elemental analysis is high resolution MS, which is often written in experimental sections as HRMS (ESI) *m/z* calcd

The format for presenting elemental analysis is journal specific, and therefore varies. The format you're asking about is consistent with the [ACS publication recommendations](http://pubs.acs.org/). [RSC guidelines](http://www.rsc.org/images/Author_guidelines_tcm18-186308.pdf) accept the the data in a slightly different format.